# Angular - How to deal with Observable of <User | null>

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm building an authentication service and I want to provide the current user to components in the Angular app.

I'm using a subject / observable of type `<User | null>` because I want to show when the user is not available. E.g. he is not logged in. However, this causes some problems so I can no longer easily access it in components. (Because of `null`)

So I was wondering how to properly deal with it. I know this problem seems pretty simple and I hope you can provide some tips or best practice as this won't be the last.

AuthService:

```js
// initially null
private readonly _currentUser = new BehaviorSubject<ApiModel.User | null>(null);
public readonly currentUser$ = this._currentUser.asObservable();
```

Component:

`{{user.email | async }}` ->

`Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Observable<User | null>`

`User` is just an interface. In the component I inject the service and then provide the observable as `user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax should be `{{ (user | async)?.email }}`.

Maybe you don't need `?` if you know the user object is always going to exist when `async` pipe is used.

Comment: The ? was needed since the value can be null.

Answer (score -1):

I think using the optional chaining operator might work (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
and having the component be {{user?.email | async}}

Comment: Hi danibranch, thanks for you quick answer. The ? was of course needed. But also the brackets as martin stated.